# Efficient way of matching two large tables on substring in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql, cross-join

I have two very large tables, mydata and mytypelist. In both tables I have a column NAME and I would like to join on them. Easier said than done, because the tables have been made by two different people and the names are just different enough to cause trouble (e.g. "John Doe" and "The John Doe").

I am currently at this point:

```
select mydata.*, mytypelist.*
from mydata
cross join mytypelist
where instr(  upper( mydata.name ), upper( mytypelist.name) ) > 0
```

Because of the size of my tables (10^6 rows), this takes ages and threatens to consume all CPU available.

Is there are more efficient way of matching two such large tables? The method works just fine for smaller tables.

Comment: Name standardization is a complex topic and not easily supported directly in SQL.

Comment: what you really need is a key to relate the records not join on name - very bad practice

Comment: Unfortunately there is no key and the names are the only way to link the two tables.